# Migrating chunks from primary shard to the other single shard takes too long

Tags: mongodb, performance, sharding, database, nosql

Each chunk move takes about 30-40 mins.

The shard key is a random looking but monotically increasing integer string which is a long sequence of digits. A "hashed" index is created for that field.

There are 150M documents each about 1.5Kb in size. The sharded collection has 10 indexes (some of them compound).

I have a total of ~11k chunks reported in sh.status(). So far I could only transfer 42 of them to the other shard.

The system consists of one `mongos`, one config server and one primary (`mongod`) shard and other (`mongod`) shard. All in the same server which has 8 cores and 32 GB ram.

I know the ideal is to use seperate machines but none of the CPUs were utilized so I thought it was good for a start.

What is your comment?

What do I need to investigate?

Is it normal?

Comment: Running a whole shard on a single machine is not *not ideal*, it's *pointless*.

Comment: you are waiting for data to be copied from one machine to the same machine - this not only doesn't help your cause (to speed up performance, I assume) it significantly slows things down.  Do you even have indication that your server was CPU bound and extra CPU utilization would somehow help?  Normally servers will be disk IO bound.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'll build a system with more machines soon but right now we don't have the resources. The system wasn't CPU bound but wasn't IO bound either. For example right now the disk is not utilized so much as you'll see when I post the iostat logs.

Comment: Here is the iostat log: http://pastie.org/9216588 and the disk is ATA WDC WD20EARX-00P (scsi) which must see 60 MBs/sec according to tests I saw on the net.

Comment: You will not have this kind of perfs (60MB/sec) for writing while you are reading on the same disk. Are you using RAID or you have just one disk ?

Comment: The machine has only one disk.

Answer (score 0):

As said on the mongodb documentation : " Sharding is the process of storing data records across multiple machines and is MongoDB’s approach to meeting the demands of data growth. As the size of the data increases, a single machine may not be sufficient to store the data nor provide an acceptable read and write throughput. Sharding solves the problem with horizontal scaling. With sharding, you add more machines to support data growth and the demands of read and write operations."

You should definitely not have your shards on the same machine. It is useless. The interest of sharding is that you scale horizontaly. So if you shard on the same machine.... You are just killing your throughput.
Your database will be faster without sharding if you have one machine.

To avoid data loss, before using sharding you should use : raid (not 0), replicaset and then sharding.

Comment: seems you're right. We're trying to gather some number of machines.